# How to group and select data based on a date and time column over a 10-minute period?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How to group and select data based on a date and time column over a 10-minute period?

**Select:**

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE datecollect IN (
SELECT generate_series(
        (SELECT min(date_trunc('minute', datecollect)) FROM tbl), 
        (SELECT max(date_trunc('minute', datecollect)) FROM tbl), 
        '10 minute'::interval));
```

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  valuex varchar,
  datecollect timestamp);

INSERT INTO tbl (valuex,datecollect) VALUES ('teste','2020-02-25 01:00:41');
INSERT INTO tbl (valuex,datecollect) VALUES ('teste','2020-02-25 01:05:36');
INSERT INTO tbl (valuex,datecollect) VALUES ('teste','2020-02-25 01:10:41');
INSERT INTO tbl (valuex,datecollect) VALUES ('teste','2020-02-25 01:15:11');
INSERT INTO tbl (valuex,datecollect) VALUES ('teste','2020-02-25 03:00:11');
INSERT INTO tbl (valuex,datecollect) VALUES ('teste','2020-02-25 03:05:41');
INSERT INTO tbl (valuex,datecollect) VALUES ('teste','2020-02-25 03:10:11');
INSERT INTO tbl (valuex,datecollect) VALUES ('teste','2020-02-25 03:15:11');
```

[SQL VIEW](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad7e3e/1)

**Output:**

```
0 records
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` your generated series to `tbl` where `datecollect` is in the 10 minute interval starting at the time in the series. This will give you all rows for a given interval; you can then aggregate as required, grouping by `pstart`. If you want to get 0 values where there are no matching values for an interval, use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT generate_series(
            MIN(date_trunc('minute', datecollect)), 
            MAX(date_trunc('minute', datecollect)), 
            '10 minute'::interval
         ) AS pstart
  FROM tbl
) dt
JOIN tbl ON tbl.datecollect > dt.pstart AND tbl.datecollect < dt.pstart + interval '10 minute'
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
pstart                  valuex  datecollect
2020-02-25T01:00:00Z    teste   2020-02-25T01:00:41Z
2020-02-25T01:00:00Z    teste   2020-02-25T01:05:36Z
2020-02-25T01:10:00Z    teste   2020-02-25T01:10:41Z
2020-02-25T01:10:00Z    teste   2020-02-25T01:15:11Z
2020-02-25T03:00:00Z    teste   2020-02-25T03:00:11Z
2020-02-25T03:00:00Z    teste   2020-02-25T03:05:41Z
2020-02-25T03:10:00Z    teste   2020-02-25T03:10:11Z
2020-02-25T03:10:00Z    teste   2020-02-25T03:15:11Z
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad7e3e/7)

Comment: How to bring only the distinct pstart values? But with the values ​​of valorx together

Comment: @LuisHenrique you would need to use a `GROUP BY` with `STRING_AGG`